# The multi-layered multi-layered puzzle competition Part 1/11: February 16th, 2013

Tags: cipher

<sub>*This is Part 1 of **[The multi-layered multi-layered puzzle competition](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A86115+is%3Aq+%22the+multi-layered+multi-layered+puzzle+competition%22)**, a 11 part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end*</sub>

<sub>Note: This is entirely a work of fiction. Any relation to actual events, people, places, or acts are purely coincidental.</sub>

<sub>Estimated solve time for Part 1: 2-3 hours total</sub>

---

Goals for Part 1:

> 1. Decode each sequence of code in its entirety. (Including the pre-competition and post-competition ciphers)
> 2. Get the names of the people who were mentioned who used to work for or work for the competition. You do not have to list their specific roles, as you will find those out in later parts.

---

The day is February 16th, 2013, or so you think it is. The surrounding landscape - what surrounding landscape? You've been knocked out and transported to the GAPSI - the Great American Puzzle Solving Institution (or African? You can't quite remember, although you're being told that it's American) for a puzzle-solving competition. You reach your hand to your pocket only to grab a piece of nostalgia - a [T-Mobile Sidekick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger_Hiptop), although you don't remember that phone having any level of capabilities compared to your [iPhone 4s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4s) - They took your iPhone 4s! Your stomach sinks to the floor as you just hope they haven't destroyed it, as that contained your friend's wedding photos with his partner, which is the only memory you have of him and his partner left before they both seemingly disappeared. Just then, you were given this piece of paper:

---

Pre-competition:

> -.-- --- ..- .----. .-.. .-.. / .-.. .- - . .-. / ..-. .. -. -.. / --- ..- - / .-- .... --- / .. / .- -- .-.-.- / / .- .- -... .- -... / .- -... -... .- -... / -... .- .- .- .- / .- -... -... .- .- / .- -... -... .- -... / -... .- -... .- .- / .- .- .- .- .- / .- -... .- -... .- / .- -... .- -... .- / -... .- .- -... .- / .- .- -... -... -... / .- .- .- .- .- / -... .- .- -... .- / .- -... .- -... -... / .- .- .- .- .- / -... .- .- -... .- / -... .- .- -... .- / .- .- -... .- .- / -... .- .- .- .- / -... .- .- .- -... / .- -... .- .- .- / -... .- .- .- -... / -... .- .- -... .- / .- .- -... -... -... / .- .- .- .- .- / -... .- .- -... .- / -... .- -... .- .- / .- .- -... .- .- / .- .- -... .- -... / .- -... -... .- -... / .- .- .- -... .- / -... .- .- -... -... / -... .- .- .- -... / .- -... -... .- -... / .- -... -... .- .- / -... .- .- .- -... / .- -... -... .- -... / .- -... .- -... .- / -... .- .- -... -... / .- -... .- .- .- / .- -... -... .- .- / .- .- -... -... .- / .- -... -... -... .- / -... .- .- -... -... / -... .- -... -... -... / -... .- -... -... -... / .- -... .- -... .- / .- .- -... .- .- / -... .- .- .- -... / .- .- .- .- .- / .- -... -... .- .- / .- .- .- -... -... / .- -... -... .- .- / .- -... -... .- -... / -... .- .- -... .- / .- .- -... -... -... / .- -... .- .- .- / .- -... -... .- .- / .- .- -... -... .- / .- .- -... .- .- / .- -... .- -... .- / -... .- .- .- -... / .- .- -... .- .- / -... .- .- -... .- / .- .- -... -... -... / .- .- .- .- .- / -... .- .- -... .- / -... .- -... -... .- / .- -... -... .- -... / -... .- .- -... -... / .- .- .- -... .- / .- .- .- .- .- / .- -... -... .- .- / -... .- .- -... .- / .- .- -... -... -... / .- -... .- .- .- / .- -... -... .- .- / .- -... .- .- -... / .- -... -... .- -... / .- .- -... .- -... / / ....- ...-- ...-- ....- / ..--- ..--- ...-- ....- ...-- ....- .---- ....- / ...-- .---- ....- ..... .---- ...-- ..--- ..... / .---- .---- ...-- ...-- .---- ....- / ....- ..--- .---- ..... ...-- ..--- .---- ..... ...-- ..--- .---- ..--- .---- ..... ....- ..--- / ....- ....- ...-- ....- / ..--- ...-- .---- .---- ..... .---- .---- ..... / ..--- .---- ....- ..... ...-- ...-- -.-.--

You take out your T-Mobile Sidekick and turn it on, expecting it to not work, but surprisingly, it does! However, it seems that it only will work for a few seconds each time. Then, you look straight ahead, and see a [smart board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_whiteboardz) that wasn't previously there a few minutes ago. On the screen, it says:

| Instructions |
| --- |
| Don't try to make it work before the competition starts. If you try to make it work (i.e. by jamming a charger into it, your device will break and you will be automatically disqualified. Also, if you manage to make it stay on for more than five seconds before the competition starts, you will also be automatically disqualified. |
| Please adhere to the rules as they are. While the competition starts randomly for everyone, the only way you can lose is by breaking the rules mentioned above and by having the slowest time to finish the 10 puzzles overall. |
| The phone that you each were given will work in a few minutes when a piece of paper falls from the ceiling through a near invisible slot. |
| When you are done decoding each sequence, put the piece of paper in the slot in the table. The machine will check after each day (there are 10 days in each competition, with 10 hours in each competition, for a total of 100 sequences over a course of 100 hours)<sup>[2]</sup> to make sure that all 10 pieces of paper are submitted properly and in order. |
| You will be provided with food and water throughout the competition, with 4 courses - breakfast, lunch, dinner, and everyone's favorite, dessert. Attempting to hoard food and water will result in immediate disqualification. |
| If you are unable to decode a sequence before the next piece of paper is given, you must keep track of everything yourself. Any writing on the paper that does not appear to be part of your solution will result in automatic disqualification by the machine. |

which you have no choice but to follow. Then, the screen flashes to show this:

|  |
| --- |
| The time is 8:00am. You will now be distributed the first part of the puzzle, which is a simple rehash on decoding Morse code. If you now turn on your T-Mobile Sidekick that you were given, you will find that it has the capabilities of 5G internet, something that no company will achieve until around 5 years and 3 months from now. The service that you are currently using (called Cryptii) won't even be around until 11/23/13<sup>[1]</sup>, and we have managed to travel into the future and retrieve the current version! Good luck to everyone, and have fun! |

---

Part 1

> .-- . .-.. -.-. --- -- . / - --- / .-. --- ..- -. -.. / .---- / --- ..-. / - .... . / -- ..- - .. -....- .-.. .- -.-- . .-. . -.. / -- ..- .-.. - .. -....- .-.. .- -.-- . .-. . -.. / -.-. .. .--. .... . .-. / .--. ..- --.. --.. .-.. . / -.-. --- -- .--. . - .. - --- -. .-.-.- / -.-- --- ..- / -- .. --. .... - / -. --- - .. -.-. . / .-. .. --. .... - / .- .-- .- -.-- / - .... .- - / - .... .. ... / .--. ..- --.. --.. .-.. . / .... .- ... / -- ..- .-.. - .. .--. .-.. . / .-.. .- -.-- . .-. ... -.-.-- / -.-- --- ..- .-. / --. --- .- .-.. / .. ... / - --- / -.. . -.-. --- -.. . / - .... . / .--. ..- --.. --.. .-.. . / .. -. / .. - ... / . -. - .. .-. . - -.-- .-.-.- / --. --- --- -.. / .-.. ..- -.-. -.- --..-- / .- -. -.. / .... .- ...- . / ..-. ..- -. .-.-.- / / ...-- ....- ..--- ...-- --..-- / ..... ....- ...-- ....- ....- ..... / ....- ..--- .---- ..... .---- .---- ...-- .---- ...-- .---- ..... ....- / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- ..--- ....- ...-- ...-- ..--- ..... / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- .---- .---- ....- ....- / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- ..--- ....- ....- ...-- / ...-- ..... ....- ..... ..... ..... ..... ..... ...-- .---- .---- ..... / .---- ...-- ...-- ....- ....- ..... ...-- .---- .---- ....- / .---- ..... ..... .---- .---- ..... ....- ..--- / .---- ..--- .---- ..... / .---- ...-- ....- ..--- .---- .---- .---- ...-- ..--- ..... .---- ..... .---- ....- --..-- / ...-- ..... .---- ..... ....- ....- .---- ..... ....- ..--- -.-.-- / ..... ....- ...-- ....- ....- ..... / ....- ..--- .---- ..... .---- .---- ...-- .---- ...-- .---- ..... ....- / .---- ....- ...-- ....- -.-.-- / / ..--- ....- .----. ...-- ..--- / ....- ...-- ...-- ....- ....- ..--- ....- ..--- ..... ....- --..-- / ....- ...-- ....- ..... ....- ...-- .---- .---- ...-- ...-- --..-- / ..--- ....- / ....- ..--- .---- ..... .---- .---- ...-- .---- ...-- .---- ..... ....- / .---- .---- ...-- ..--- -.-.-- / / ...-- ....- ..--- ...-- / .---- .---- ....- ..--- .---- ..... / ..... ....- ...-- ....- ....- ..... / ...-- ...-- ...-- ....- ..... ..--- ..--.. / ..... ....- ...-- ....- ....- ..... / ....- ..--- .---- ..... .---- .---- ...-- .---- ...-- .---- ..... ....- / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- ..--- ....- ...-- ...-- ..--- ..... / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- .---- .---- ....- ....- / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- ..--- ....- ....- ...-- / ..--- ....- ....- ...-- / .---- .---- / ..--- ...-- ....- ..... ..--- ..--- .---- ..... / ..--- ....- ...-- ....- ..--- ..... .---- ..... / ...-- ...-- ...-- ....- ..... ..--- --..-- / .---- ....- ...-- ....- ...-- ...-- .----. ....- ....- / ..... ....- ...-- ....- ....- ..... -.-.-- / ..... ..--- .---- ..... ...-- .---- ...-- .---- / ..--- ...-- .---- ..... ....- ..--- .---- ..... .----. ....- ...-- / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- .---- ..... / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- ..--- ....- ...-- ...-- ..--- ..--- / ---... / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- ..--- ....- ....- ...-- / ..--- ....- ....- ...-- ...-- ...-- .----. ....- ....- / ....- ...-- ...-- ....- ...-- ..--- .---- ..... / ..--- ..... ..--- ....- ...-- ...-- .---- ....- / ...-- ....- ..--- .---- / ..--- ....- ...-- ....- ..--- ..... .---- ..... --..-- / ...-- .---- ..--- ....- ..--- ..... .---- ..... / ..... ....- ...-- ....- ....- ..... / ....- ...-- .---- ..... .---- ..... ...-- ..--- / ....- ....- ...-- ....- / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- ..--- ....- ...-- ...-- ..--- ..... / ..--- ....- ....- ....- / ..--- ....- ....- ...-- -.-.-- / ..--- ....- .----. ...-- ..--- / ....- ...-- ...-- ....- ....- ..--- ....- ..--- ..... ....- --..-- / .---- ..--- ....- ..... ....- ....- / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- .---- .---- ....- ....- .----. ....- ...-- / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- .---- ..... / .---- ...-- .---- .---- ....- ...-- .---- ..... -.-.-- / / .---- ..--- ....- ..... ....- ....- -....- / / .---- ..--- ....- ..... ....- ....- / ..... ..--- ..--- ...-- .---- .---- ....- ....- ..--.. / ..... ....- ...-- ....- ....- ..... .----. ....- ..--- .---- ..... / ..--- .---- ..--- ....- ....- ..--- .---- ..... .---- ....- -.-.-- / .---- .---- ...-- ...-- .---- ....- / .---- ....- ...-- ....- ...-- ...-- .----. ....- ....- / .---- ...-- ...-- ....- ...-- ..--- .---- ..... / .---- ..--- .---- .---- .---- ...-- ..--- ..... -.-.-- / ...-- ....- ..--- ...-- --..-- / .---- .---- ...-- ...-- .---- ....- / ...-- ....- ...-- ...-- .---- ..... / ...-- ..--- ...-- ....- ....- ..--- .---- ..... / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- ..--- ....- ...-- ...-- ..--- ..--- / -....- / ..... ....- ...-- ....- ....- ..... / ....- ...-- ....- ....- ..--- ....- ...-- .---- ...-- .---- / ...-- ...-- .---- ..... .---- ..... .---- ....- / ....- ....- ...-- ....- / ..--- .---- ..--- ....- ...-- ...-- ..--- ....- ....- ...-- ..--- ...-- / ...-- ..--- .---- .---- ..--- ..... ..--- ....- ...-- ...-- ..--- ..--- / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- .---- ..... / ....- ..--- .---- ..... ....- ...-- ....- ....- / ...-- ....- ..--- .---- / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- .---- .---- ....- ....- / ...-- ....- ...-- .---- .---- ....- / ...-- ..... ....- ..... ..... ..... ..... ..... ...-- .---- .---- ..... / ....- ....- ..--- ...-- .---- .---- ....- ....- / ..... ....- ...-- ....- ....- ..... .----. .---- ....- / ...-- ..... ....- ..--- ...-- ....- ...-- ..--- ..--- ....- ....- ...-- .---- ..... .---- ....- / ...-- ..--- .---- ..... / ..... ....- ...-- ....- ....- ..... .----. .---- ....- / ..--- .---- ..--- ....- ...-- ...-- ..--- ....- ....- ...-- ..--- ...-- -.-.--

---

You laugh to yourself in disgust at how easy it was to decode everything in that first part, although what you forgot was that if the machine found even the slightest discrepancy on your paper, you would automatically lose the competition. The ceiling distributes the second piece of paper as the smart board flashes at 8:30am. You're already hungry, because even though you were told breakfast (a nice meal of 2 eggs, 5 slices of bacon, and 3 pieces of French toast, by the way) was going to be at 9:00am, you haven't eaten anything for 16 hours. You then start to work on the second piece of paper. However, as you touch it, something appears to shock you, and the smart board screen flashes to this:

|  |
| --- |
| Time: 8:31am |
| ⚠Warning⚠ |
| This piece of paper has been detected by the machine to contain forbidden content. If you start decoding this at any point and to any length, correct or incorrect, you will be automatically disqualified. Do you wish to decode this? |
| [Yes] [No] |

You facepalm in disgust. First your phone, which contains the last memories of your friend and his partner, has been taken away without consent, and now this stupid machine is saying you'll be disqualified if you decode *a literal sequence*? You go to the machine and press [No], which then gives the following prompt:

|  |
| --- |
| Your choice: [No] |
| Please put the paper containing the forbidden content in the desk slot. Failure to do so by 6:00pm will result in immediate disqualification. |

You roll your eyeballs in disgust. *"Why would a machine be wanting me to not decode a sequence containing so-called "forbidden information" when I'm in a competition about decoding said information?"* you think to yourself. You roll your eyeballs once more and then get to decoding the second piece of paper. Although, one thing strikes you as rather weird - why is there plain English on the sheet?

---

Part 2

> Hrz 3te uhv4rl z8u yzx? F66v, g0si 42i o9 ehd8hl73 ru1hg4rl d2 kexsiy 7oid. Eqc2, vuc 56 (95pg4rf6y6 1m) wyusm t0pi e6 1hvx y2r Tocwj w2ke hex v8ngzh y9 7oe asn87 4hzvj 37 oay s1y5 b0ud h2nyaxxjb6, hny wfxy6, a7p tz 7oe xsu3rz hvzj vrln vjkyp1ey. Xm36 tevrx duht hi 23ys bz gmypri9k k95 mocfnxqln 4rk95taemt8 2u y0yw u1zwzv x2rltd xt 7nre dywy bvu 3e1y1'1 axgnxrutzp4 31jlfhjx nuy 4rk9 7oae qfi uhvz fjy1 iu2kjx.
>
> usenumbers
>
> usevigenerecipher
>
> usebaconcipher
>
> -Y1k o1 rtdvje vri 821 Pvvy l 2m t3i h9zweemy32u-
>
> awefu nhbve gunha vegun hbvfg vnibv egvnh awffv ohbve fuoha vefvn havef uoiav ffuoh awefv nhbve fuoha vfgvn hawfg unhav ffuoi awefu nibve fuoia wefvn hawfg uohav ffuni avfgv nhave fvoia vfgvn hawef uoiav efunh awegu niawe guoha vegun iawef unhav egvnh bvegu niave gunhb veguo hbweg vnhav ffuni awffv niawf fuoha vfguo hbwef uniav ffuoh awffv nhawe fvohb vfgun haweg uniav ffuni bvefv ohavf gunib wefuo havef uoiav efunh bvefv niave gunib vegun iavff uoiaw eguoh avegv ohbwe fvohb wefvo haweg uoiaw ffunh bvegu nhbwf fuoha wefvn hawfg vnhbv egunh awegv nhbve fvoha vfguo iawef vnibv egvni bvegv ohave fuoha vefun hbvff uohbv ffvoh avegu nhave fvoha wefvn hbvef vnhbw ffuni bvegu niawe fvohb vfguo hbveg unhav ffuoh awfgu nhbve gunia vegun iavef vnhaw efvni awefu niawe fuoha vefun hbwef unhbw egvnh awffv ohawe fuoha wefvn hawfg unhav ffuoh avfgv nhbve guoha vefun iaveg unhav eguoh bvffu nhave guoia wefuo hbweg uoiav efvnh bvegu nibvf gunhb vffvn hbvef uoibv efuni avffu ohawe guoha vegun hawef uoiav ffuoh avfgv nhbve funia wefun havef unhbv eguni bvefv nhave gunia wegun hbweg vnhav eguni awefu nhbve gunha vegun hbvfg vnibv ffvnh avfgv nhave gunia vefvo hbweg vnibv egvni bvegv ohawe fuoib vffun hbwef uohaw ffvoh awffv ohawf gunha vegun havfg uoiaw egunh awffu nhbwe funhb vffvn havef uohbw egunh awffu nhbwe funha veguo hbweg vnhav eguoi avffu ohave funia vfguo iawef uoiaw ffunh awefv nhbve gunha vffvn hbvef uohaw efvnh bvegu nhbwf funha wefvn iawff uoiaw ffuoi awefv nibve fvohb wegun havef vnhaw ffvnh avffu niawe fvnia vefun iaveg uohav efuoi awffv ohawe fuoib vefun iavff unhav ffuni awegu nibvf fvoha vegvn havef vnhaw ffuoh avfgv niave gunhb vffuo hawef uniav egvoh bvefv nhbwf funha vfgvn hbwff uniav egvnh awefu nibve fuoia vffun hbvfg vnhaw efunh avegv niawe guoia vegvn hbweg uohav egvnh avfgu ohawe fvohb vegvo havef vnhbw efvnh avefu nhavf gunib wefuo hbvef uoiav efvoh awegv ohbwe fvoia vfguo iawef uniav ffunh avefu ohavf guoia vfguo iavfg vnhaw efunh bvfgu niave funha vffvo havef vnhbv ffuoh avfgv niave gunhb vfgvn hbweg uohav egvnh bvegu nhbvf fvnha vfgun hawef vnhaw ffuoi bvefv nhave fvoha vffun hawff vnhbw efvnh bvefv ohavf fvnha vfgvo iavfg uohav ffuoh bvegu nhbwf fuoha vfgun

---

You sigh in disgust as you once again put the deciphered cipher into the desk slot. The room that you're in darkens as the board flashes to show this text:

|  |
| --- |
| Congratulations! |
| Time: 10:30am |

That's weird. You don't remember this happening after decoding the last sequence. Maybe this happens after you decode a sequence that's just a bit too long. Anyways, you're now wondering what's going on in the inner depths of this competition. How many people are there? Are you the only person in this competition? However, you don't have time to wonder that as the next paper falls to the desk nicely.

---

Part 3

> |2;@C 2??@F?46>6?E\
>
> (6==[ E:>6 7@C 2 3C62< 96C6] *@F >:89E H2?E E@ <?@H E92E 6:E96C @?6 @7 @FC 4FCC6?E 6>A=@J66D @C @?6 @7 @FC 7@C>6C 6>A=@J66D 92D 366? D?62<:?8 AC:G2E6 4@?G6CD2E:@?D 36EH66? $FD2?[ E96 @C82?:K6C 7@ E9:D J62C=J 4@>A6E:E:@? 2?5 D@>6 7@C>6C 6>A=@J66D[ 2?5 H6 ;FDE H2?E J@F E@ <?@H E92E H6 >:89E 92G6 E@ <66A J@F 7@C 2 4@FA=6 >@C6 52JD 5F6 E@ E96 3F:=5:?8 36:?8 @? =@4<5@H? 7@C C:89E ?@H] %9:D :D ?@E A2CE @7 E96 4@>A6E:E:@?[ D@ E92?<D 7@C =6EE:?8 FD 4=62C E92E FA 7@C J@F] }@E6 E92E 564@5:?8 2?J AC:G2E6 :?7@C>2E:@? E92E >:89E 92G6 366? =62<65 H:== C6DF=E :? :>>65:2E6 5:DBF2=:7:42E:@? 27E6C E96 D2>6 52J 2E ei__A>
>
> \\
>
> p3;[ v3@G2 &][ ;F?8 ?6C =39 ?@JC 83 8CJJ KC ?@398 8FC 46G:?8C G2D36K?8G32 8F?8V7 EC88G2E JC?ICBn
>
> 'VK 7366=[ u97?2] ' H978 B32V8 I23; ;F?8V7 E3G2E 32]
>
> *GIC rC8C6 ?2B (C6CK= BGB2V8 I23;] yF= K978 8FG7 ICC4 F?44C2G2En
>
> yF= BGB2V8 =39 A?JJ ?983K?8GA J3AIB3;2 ?8 8FC @CEG22G2E 3D 8FC A3K4C8G8G32[ JGIC ;C F?B B32C 8FC 46C:G397 ` =C?67n yF= BGB2V8 =39 F?:C 8;3 4C34JC E3 G283 8FC 4?4C6 633K ?8 8FC 7?KC 8GKC[ JGIC ;C 78344CB B3G2E g =C?67 ?E3n yF= B32V8 ;C F?:C ? 7CA96G8= A?KC6? G2 8F?8 633Kn yF=\
>
> qF[ 73 G8V7 H978 Q;F= 8FG7Q 36 Q;F= 8F?8Q ?J;?=7n '7 8FG7 ? E?KC 83 =39n
>
> p3[ @98\
>
> p3[ @98 ;F?8n 'D 8FG7 EC87 JC?ICB 83 8FC 49@JGA[ ;CV6C\
>
> {C?F[ =39V:C 83JB C:C6=32C 8FG7] yCVJJ @C 69G2CB] &3;C:C6\
>
> v3@G2[ ' B32V8 DCCJ JGIC =39 92BC678?2B]
>
> yCJJ[ GD =39 DCCJ 8F?8 ;?=[ 8FC2 ' 59G8] vFG7 G7 =396 D?9J8 ?2B =396 D?9J8 32J=]

---

When you put this in the desk slot, the smart board flashes to say:

|  |
| --- |
| Part 4/10 done! |
| Time: 10:31am |

---

This confuses you. First of all, you only remember decoding two parts. Second of all, there's no way you managed to decode all of that in only 1 minute. Third, you're sweating profusely, and hungry and thirsty at that. You don't even remember being served a drink at breakfast. Then, you get this piece of paper.

---

Part 4

> Crgre urer. V xabj gung gurer'f cebonoyl ab jnl gung lbh'er tbvat gb frr guvf, ohg V whfg jnagrq lbh gb xabj gung jungrire lbh qb, qba'g chg guvf va gur qrfx fybg. V'ir nyernql evttrq gung fghcvq znpuvar gb znxr fher gung jungrire unccraf, lbh pna riraghnyyl tb serr. Whfg cyrnfr, jnvg hagvy ng yrnfg 1:55cz gb chg guvf vagb gur qrfx fybg. Gur znpuvar vf nyernql evttrq jurer vg frrzf gung gvzr vf tbvat snfgre be fybjre guna vg npghnyyl vf. Lbh xabj jung? Fvapr V fgvyy unir erzbgr npprff gb gur znpuvar (Fhfna sbetbg gb gnxr vg njnl nsgre V jnf sverq), fb V'yy znxr vg frrz yvxr 0 ubhef unir cnffrq va jung unf npghnyyl orra 65 zvahgrf. Ubjrire, bar guvat gb xrrc va zvaq: Ybbx ohfl. Vs gur crbcyr jub fcrpvnyvmr jvgu unaqvat bhg sbbq fhfcrpg n guvat, gurl'yy xabj gung fbzrguvat'f hc. Fb, yrg'f jnvg hagvy, yrg'f fnl, 8:55cz hagvy V zbir gvzr sbejneq. Qvaare qbrfa'g trg qryvirerq hagvy 2:85cz, naq qrffreg 3:05cz, fb yhpxvyl lbh fubhyq or svar hagvy ng yrnfg gbzbeebj.

---

You're happy about this. First, of all, it seems that after all, you are getting help, and not just going to be stuck here for all eternity. Second of all, you might get some answers for once. Third of all, you only have to wait for just less than an hour (as you have already "spent" 4 hours decoding this "mess") "spending time" decoding said "mess". Then, you look at the board to see that the time is now 6:00pm. You go to put the slip (undecoded of course) in the desk slot, which sets off an alarm? The room flashes red and blue and the board flashes to show this message:

|  |
| --- |
| ⚠WARNING⚠ |
| All employees, former and current, along with all other staff MUST evacuate the building due to an alert coming from RM3615 on the 5th floor. Competitors MUST STAY IN THEIR ROOMS FOR THE TIME BEING. WE WILL RETURN 12 HOURS LATER TO ASSESS THE FORBIDDEN CONTENT. |

You look outside of your room through the gap your mail slot provides, and you see rooms numbered "3615a", "3615b", "3615d", and so on, although you're unable to think very clearly as there is a seemingly slow-acting sleeping gas filling the room from somewhere, so you're not really sure. You see someone walking, and they give you one final piece of paper, and then slam the mail slot shut. You then hear a key and lock, and you're left with the piece of paper that the moving figure gave you.

---

Post Competition sequence

> Crgre urer. V'z abg fher vs V'z tbvat gb or noyr gb svther bhg ubj gb trg lbh bhg abj. Qba'g jbeel, lbh'er gur bayl bar va guvf pbzcrgvgvba. Ubjrire, ab znggre ubj snfg lbh jrer, gur obneq jvyy nyjnlf fubj lbh nf gur ynfg cynpr svavfure. Vg'f whfg ubj vg jbexf. Qba'g jbeel, V unir gur cncref lbh frrz gb unir shyyl qrpbqrq. Fb V thrff guvf vf whfg tbvat gb or n tbbqolr. Lbh fubhyq xabj gung gurer'f npghnyyl n frperg qbbe haqre gur qrfx, juvpu yrnqf gb n snyfr sybbe juvpu yrnqf gb n fgnvepnfr gb gur qrcguf bs guvf fghcvq cynpr. Gung'f nyy V'yy or noyr gb gryy lbh. Znl jr frr rnpu bgure va gur shgher.

---

Notes

---

<sup>[1]</sup>[Source](https://github.com/cryptii/cryptii/releases?page=2)

<sup>[2]</sup>Not actually

> Also sorry for the really long and comprehensive story, it really could've taken me a day instead of the 2 it actually took me to make this.
>
> I actually do not remember why I decided to write a long and comprehensive story and background for this, so I apologize for that.

---

Hints

---

Hint 1

> Don't worry, the instructions don't apply to you as much as it might seem they do. Please make sure to drink and eat plenty regularly, and try to take plenty of breaks throughout the day.

Hint 2

> Use the already decrypted text to your advantage!

Hint 3

> If you're stuck on a part, I'm trying to stick to familiarity here, so look at my previous ciphers and the answers as much as you want!

Hint 4

> havefun!

Comment: While this looks like a fun puzzle, I would caution you against posting too many similar puzzles in a short amount of time.  If people keep seeing the same thing over and over, they are likely to start downvoting out of fatigue.  A certain type of puzzle might be fun and engaging the first time, but quickly becomes boring and tedious after a number of repetitions.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I'll definitely keep that in mind